# Two While Loops, Second Returns Empty Array?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm experimenting with MySQLi and using the following code to check differences for how I should approach my array formatting/usage for `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

here is my code:

```
include "Database.php"; 

$ArrayQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accountinformation");


while ($ArrayResults = $ArrayQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo count($ArrayResults);
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<br><br><bR><br>";
    $Empty = array();
while ($ArrayResult = $ArrayQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    foreach ($ArrayResult AS $ArrayRes)
    {
        $Empty[] = $ArrayRes;
    }
}

print_r($Empty);
```

The problem is, that i'm using the same `Variable` for my while loop, the first one returns `3` then `3` Which is expected.

But the problem is, with my second query; it returns a blank array

`array( )` when `print_r();`

and when I do:

```
while ($ArrayResult = $ArrayQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    print_r($ArrayResult);
}
```

For my Second while loop, it returns nothing for output.

I have checked my variables `$ArrayResults` and `$ArrayResult` are not duplicates, they are in fact unique.

Why is my second while loop returning nothing when my first one is working?

**Update**

When I produce a second query into the mixture with a different starting variable:

```
$ArrayQuer = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accountinformation");
```

and modify my second while loop:

```
while ($ArrayResult = $ArrayQuer->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    print_r($ArrayResult);
}
```

I get the expected output? So is it a case of MySQLi not allowing the same parameters to be used twice throughout the script?

Comment: Why do you expect it to fetch anything after it has already finished fetching all the results? Rewind it to the first row using [`$ArrayQuery->data_seek(0)`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php#85629), or just use the already fetched result array.

Comment: @DCoder shoudln't it load up the data within my `$ArrayQuery` to be used in another while loop? I understand it's not exactly in best practice to use a situation like this; but i'm just finding out the kinks within MySQLI and seeing what would work; to what doesnt. Because if i move over to `mysql_*` functions; It would produce the expected output by using `$ArrayQuery` Twice in two different while loops.

Comment: Look at the activity in your first code sample: 1) run a query 2) fetch all of its results 3) fetch all of its results again. Your update inserts another step, "run another query", before step 3, and you get the result you expect. This is completely identical to the way mysql_* functions would handle the situation.

Comment: But I don't see the point in running two queries to return the exact same thing. I wont use this setup in a production environment; but this is for my own tweaks and kinks book.

Comment: `$ArrayQuery` internally keeps track of the index of the next row to be fetched. When your first `while` loop ends, `$ArrayQuery` has fetched all the results and this index is equal to the number of rows fetched. Your second `while` loop then asks it to for each remaining result, but *there are no further results* to give, because the first loop took it all and the index says so. When you rewind `$ArrayQuery` using Daryl Gill's answer (which is exactly what I suggested in my first comment), this internal index is reset and the second loop starts from the first row again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysqli_data_seek
>
> Adjusts the result pointer to an arbitrary row in the
> result

```
while ($ArrayResults = $ArrayQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo count($ArrayResults);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br><br><bR><br>";
    mysqli_data_seek($ArrayQuery,0); // Addition Made Here
        $Empty = array();
    while ($ArrayResult = $ArrayQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        foreach ($ArrayResult AS $ArrayRes)
        {
            $Empty[] = $ArrayRes;
        }
    }
    print_r($Empty);
```

To re-use an already fetched array; you should use `mysqli_data_seek();` (*Notice I have added it above your `$Empty Variable*) This should be the problem.

See the manual here:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

*Think of this scenario; Why would you re-buy something you already own?*

*Fits perfectly in your case*